# insertRule ":before" for all but some

Tags: javascript, css

I can successfully "null's" all rules that consist ":before {content:}" using :

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.main *:before {content: " "!important;}',0);
```

Is there is a way to do that for all but some?
Let's say leaving 
".main .submain:before" untouched?

I was trying as per suggestion:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.main *:not(.submain):before {content: " "!important;}',0);
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.
Then  I was trying to insert new content attribute in previously "nulled" rules using:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.main .submain:before {content: "\fxxx"!important;}',0);
```

That doesn't work either.

CSS as follow:

```
.main {
  color: #bebedc;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
.main .submain:before{content:"\fzzz"}
.main .submain1:before{content:"\fxxx"}
.......................
.main .submain_n:before{content:"\fnnn"}
```

May be it is possible to do that using "querySelector('.submain')..."?
Greatly appreciate for suggestion.

The goal is to replace native CSS ":before content" of the "video js" player by custom ones. So, the ".main" class in my sample is actually ". video-js" class.

Below the full tree of HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,initial-scale=1.0">

<title>Video JS </title>


<link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<video id="myPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin "  width="640" height="273" poster="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png"  controls preload="auto" 
data-setup='{}'>
<source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>

</video>

<script>

document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.video-js *:before {content: " "!important;}',0);//---this "nulls"------all pseudo elements


//document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.video-js * :not(.vjs-big-play-button):before {content: " "!important;}',0);//--attempt to leave ".vjs-big-play-button" untouched

//document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.video-js *.vjs-big-play-button:before {content: "\f101"!important;}',0);//--attempt to re-insert ".vjs-big-play-button" after "nulling"


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show your tree structure.

Comment: CSS structure, post edited

Comment: No, the **tree** structure: your HTML. (well CSS is actually useful too, so leave it)

Comment: HTML tree structure is a standard/basic video js implementation

Comment: We still need to see it in order to be able to give you the correct CSS rules you need.

Comment: Full HTML tree added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unsuccessful attempts to resolve this task by on line code I came up with the following:

First - using:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.video-js *:before {content: " "!important;}',0);
```

inserts :before {content: " ";} in every element even if it was not there before (Actually this is how it suppose to be).

However:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.video-js * :not(.vjs-icon-placeholder ):before {content: " "!important;}',0);
```

"nulling" all contents only where they where defined exclude rule ".vjs-icon-placeholder"

I can't explain - why it doesn't insert extra ":before" this time.

Next line:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.video-js * .vjs-icon-placeholder:before {content: " "!important;}',0);
```

"nulling" all contents of ".vjs-icon-placeholder" rule only. I couldn't mange to combine these two steps in one line.

And the last step - I create new style sheet by duplicating the rule of the element  I want to preserve with initial (before "nulling") content.

In my case:

```
 .video-js .vjs-big-play-button .vjs-icon-placeholder:before {
content: "\f101"!important;
}
```

Not super elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors can be negated using the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class. (However it would be best to have the original `content` property only apply to the desired elements from the beginning.)

```css
div:before {
  content: "before ";
}

.main *:not(.submain):before {
  content: "" !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">main
  <div class="submain">submain</div>
  <div class="foobar">foobar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 'using the :not() pseudo-class' would be the answer, but  I can't find out - how

Comment: `.main *:not(.submain):before` select the `:before` pseudo-element for any tags inside of `.main` except for `.submain`

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that this approach doesn't work. Post revised/edited.